# Official or default Bitcoin wallet for Android

Tags: wallet, client, android

I'm new to cryptocurrencies, and I noticed that both Litecoin and Dogecoin have official wallet apps for Android.

Does Bitcoin similarly have an official Android wallet app? If not, is there a community standard or some widely used app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the Bitcoin Foundation or any similar authority has designated an official or preferred Android app, not in the same way that Bitcoin Core is the "official" desktop client because it is the reference implementation.

But the most popular one seems to be [Bitcoin Wallet by Andreas Schildbach](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet).